# Storing Universities in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-normalization

We are building our site and we are constantly adding new universities. I have a class that manages a lot of this. The question is, when people register, should we store the university they attend as the full string in the database, or convert each university to a unique int and store this, or create a new table of all the universities and just add them in manually as we add more schools to our system, then just store the primary_key of the chosen school in the users table? The easiest would be just to store the string. But I feel this may be inefficient.

Comment: The latter.  Definitely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think storing the full string every time is very inefficient. I would tackle this by storing just the `universityId` number for each user, and then use SQL querys to retrieve whatever information you need.

This way you will avoid duplicity in your data (e.g.: Different users from the same university entering different strings)

Answer (score 3):

you should definitely create another table for universities and store PK of this table in another tables , so you can perform operations on these tables easier

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the previous answers.  You definitely want to use a university id primary key, and not just a string with the university name!  Designing your database in this way is called normalization.  Take a look at [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283878), for an introduction to normalization including a bit of discussion on why you need it.